# Android development on Coby Kyros?

Tags: android

Has anyone had luck developing for the Android Market using the Coby Kyros internet tab for testing?  And also, are tablet and phone builds for the Android market separated into their own store categories like the way Apple does it; Mac app store, iPad store, iPhone store?
Thanks,
Nick